# How to update the value from PHP variable into database

Tags: php, database, sql-update

everyone.

I have a problem with updating value into database.

Now, I have $SumTotal as a PHP variable. I want to update value in database by using value in $SumTotal.

I try it but it doesn't work. The value in database is 0.

here is my code

```
$strSQL3 = "UPDATE OrderCustomer SET TotalPrice = '".$SumTotal."' WHERE OrderCustomerID = '".$_SESSION["OrderCustomerID"]."' ";
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: All i see is a string called `$strSQL3`. What do you do with that string?

Comment: $strSQL3 is a query variable.
I use like this $objQuery3 = mysql_query($strSQL3);

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, this code should work for you.

```
{
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$SumTotal="**Some value**";
//**QUERY**
$strSQL3= "UPDATE OrderCustomer".
       "SET Totalprice= $SumTotal".
       "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id" ;

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $strSQL3, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: _"**Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."_

Comment: mysql_* are deprecated. So, please don't encourage the use of mysql_*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would make sure that `$SumTotal` and `$_SESSION['OrderCustomerID']` are equal to what they are meant to be equal to.

I would do something like: `echo "$SumTotal";` and `echo $_SESSION['OrderCustomerID'];` to check these variables.

Then, you could do the following:

- Make sure that the database **is actually selected** (to select the database in your query, you can use `UPDATE databasename.table` (where `table` is equal to OrderCustomer in your case)
- Check for errors in your query by adding `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of your query.
- Use the following at the very top of your PHP document to show all errors that have occurred: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/3593228.

In addition to this, make sure that your query is actually being executed.

You can do this by using the `mysql_query` function as follows:

`$strSQL3 = mysql_query("UPDATE databasename.OrderCustomer SET TotalPrice = '$SumTotal' WHERE OrderCustomerID = '" . $_SESSION["OrderCustomerID"] . "'");`

**Also,** before someone beats me to it, you should be using PDO or MySQL Improved, yada yada yada.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this piece of [code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_update_php.htm).

This will definitely work, i have tried this personally.

**Edit**: (Pulled from link)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];

$sql = "UPDATE employee ".
       "SET emp_salary = $emp_salary ".
       "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id" ;

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee ID</td>
<td><input name="emp_id" type="text" id="emp_id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Salary</td>
<td><input name="emp_salary" type="text" id="emp_salary"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```